# Ref doesn't change when it's in an array in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I have 3 color pickers, and when I choose the color I want it to be displayed in the div#app. However, it seems like the colors pickers can't change the values of the colors which are refs, I think it's because the array takes a copy of the refs and changed and not the reference (address), and I don't know how to solve this issue.

These are the initial colors:

```css
:root {
    --custom-color: #ff0;
    --custom-color-body: #00ff;
    --custom-color-footer: #FF000F;
}
```

and this is the part of the color pickers

```js
<template>
    <VMenu v-for="(color, index) in selectedColors" :key="index" location="bottom">
        <template #activator="{ props }">
            <VBtn width="260" :color="color" v-bind="props">
                <p class="p-color">Header Color <br /><span class="text-uppercase">{{ color
                }}</span></p>
                <p></p>
            </VBtn>
        </template>
        <VList>
            <VColorPicker hide-inputs="true" v-model="ColorHeader" />
        </VList>
    </VMenu>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const bgColorHeader = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--custom-color');
const bgColorBody = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--custom-color-body');
const bgColorFooter = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--custom-color-footer');
const ColorHeader = ref(bgColorHeader.toString());
const ColorBody = ref(bgColorBody.toString());
const ColorFooter = ref(bgColorFooter.toString());
const selectedColors = [ColorHeader.value, ColorBody.value, ColorFooter.value];
</script>
```

and this is the result that I want it to be changed

```js
<div id="app">
                    <div class="app">
                        <div class="header" :style="'background-color:' + selectedColors[0] + '!important;'">
                            <h1>Header</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content" :style="'background-color:' + selectedColors[1] + '!important;'">
                            <p>This is the main content area.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer" :style="'background-color:' + selectedColors[2] + '!important;'">
                            <p>Footer</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Not sure, I think your `selectedColors` should hold the _ref_ variables and not just the values, as the _ref_ is reactive.

Comment: This sentence doesn't make sense to me grammatically:  _the array takes a copy of the refs and changed and not the reference (address)_

Comment: @Wyck i meant that when the refs are in an array and we changed them through the array like array[i] = someValue; we can see the change only if we use array[i] and not the directly the name of the ref

Answer (score 0):

Your array dereferences your ref, therefore it's a `string[]` and not a `Ref<string>[]`. Regular arrays aren't reactive.

You'll want to make an array using your refs and 'it their values.

And since Vue's templates only "automagically" unwrap "top-level refs", you'll have to use `myArr[myIndex].value` instead of just `myArr[myIndex]`.

```
// setup
const selectedColors = [ColorHeader, ColorBody, ColorFooter];
```

Your `v-for` might not need to change, since `color` is now a ref.